# Getting Google Custom Search to index your site

Tags: indexing

I've just implemented this [site](http://www.saferoutesga.org/). I'm trying to get Google Custom Search to work for my site but am coming up short.  I've done a couple of things:

- Added "http://www.saferoutesga.org" as a site in the control panel and set "Dynamically extract links from this page and add them to my search engine" with the "Include all partial sites this page links to" option.
- Explicitly fed it a page to index: http://www.saferoutesga.org/Sitemap
- Setup a sitemap file and registered it: http://www.saferoutesga.org/sitemap.axd

The *only* thing I've gotten to work is the second bullet above.  You'll see if you use the search bar included in the footer of the site.  I'd like to avoid explicitly indexing each and every page if I can.  Besides, I wouldn't want to remember to manually re-index after every update.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submitting a site to Google for indexing doesn't *guarantee* it will happen immediately.

The `sitemap` aspect *should* speed-up the indexing time, but it's still up to them how/when they do.

One way to help bump your site up in the indexing queue, from what I understand, is to make sure that a) it has legitimate content, and b) that content is being updated somewhat frequently.

If new items are published via RSS, it seems to help, too.

Have you put a robots.txt in place?

Ultimately, though, it's up to the indexer when and how often it gets indexed.